# Fluentd JSON string parsing with multiple data type in array

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logging, fluentd

I am trying to set up a logging pipeline with Fluentd and elastic search. One of my log patterns looks like the following:

```json
{
  "key": "value",
  "inputs": [
    [
      "2023-01-16T04: 45: 12.238Z",
      {
        "type": "channel",
        "subtype": "profile",
        "data": {
          "firstName": "Customer"
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The issue with this structure is that the first object in the inner array `date` is a string. Whenever Flunetd is trying to write it to ES, it throws an exception with error code 400, and following message

```
#0 dump an error event: error_class=Fluent::Plugin::ElasticsearchErrorHandler::ElasticsearchError error="400 - Rejected by Elasticsearch [error type]: illegal_argument_exception [reason]: 'can't merge a non object mapping [data.inputs] with an object mapping'" location=nil
```

What is the way forward?

When I remove this date from the array, it is getting synced correctly to ES.

Comment: Did you try to remove it from the array? Please add your relevant fluentd config to your question.

Comment: `inputs` is an array with a nested array in that sample JSON. Would this contain multiple arrays or one array with one timestamp and multiple objects? Please update that sample if required.

Comment: `Input` can have have multiple object in the parent array but it will always have timestamp as a first object of inner array. Yes, I tried to remove it then it worked fine but I need to keep this.

Comment: Right, I think you can extract that to some other JSON KV pair and normalize this one as your needed it to be pushed to ES.